# How can a object in typescript get one or more unassigned property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
type ObjectDescriptor<D, M> = {
  data?: D;
  methods?: M & ThisType<D & M>; // Type of 'this' in methods is D & M
};

function makeObject<D, M>(desc: ObjectDescriptor<D, M>): D & M {
  let data: object = desc.data || {};
  let methods: object = desc.methods || {};
  return { ...data, ...methods } as D & M;
}

let obj123 = makeObject({
  data: {
    x: 20,
    y: 50,
    moveBy(dx: number, dy: number) {
      this.x += dx; // Strongly typed this
      this.y += dy; // Strongly typed this
    },
  },
  methods: { x: 0, y: 0 },
});

console.dir(obj123);

const nemObj = { method: obj123.moveBy };

nemObj.method(5, 5);
# console.dir(nemObj); // here newObj also getting two extra property x and y but how????
```

I created an Object called `obj123` using the function called `makeObject()` and then I am assigning the method of this object to another Object called `nemObj` but this `nemObj` also getting the `x` and `y` property from the previous object. How is this happening?

Comment: You forgot to bind `moveBy` to the original object: https://tsplay.dev/mL8A2m If you don't bind, then the `this` in `moveBy` is a reference to `nemObj`.

Comment: Okay, if I bind the actual object then the problem goes away. But if I don't bind then I am only providing the reference to the method, so, then how does the object get the other two variables e.g. x and y

Comment: It doesn't need to. You're assigning to `this.x` and `this.y`. Why would it need to get it from elsewhere?